# How to send Array by Post Method to server and make it arrive as an Array (Not an Object)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, post

My problem is very simple in the fact, but I can't find a way to solve it.

**I want to send an array by Post method by XMLHttpRequest.**

I try to send an array like this :

```
[Value1, Value2, Value3]
```

However, **the header change my array and transform it in Object** :

```
{ 0:Value1, 1:Value2, 2:Value3}
```

Now, I understand that array and object are tied. But I would like to find a way to not change my array into an object.

I would like my array arriving like this to the server :

```
 [Value1, Value2, Value3]
```

Say otherwise, **I want it to stay an array and not become an object.**

But I don't find a way to do it. Is this Possible ?
And if yes, how ?

I've tried to change the type/content of the header but it have'nt work.

Comment: Send it as json string maybe? With `JSON.stringify(arr)`

Answer (score 0):

```
const myArray = [Value1, Value2, Value3];
http.post<any>(myUrl, myArray);
```

You can't send more individual value, you can send only one object.
Just include your array in a variable and send it